# How to configure 2nd Quadrature Decoder IO pins in Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino-ide, arduino-due, atmel-studio, rotary-encoder, assembly

I am working to read two quadrature encoders using a single Arduino DUE, as part of my summer vacations project. According to the following link
http://atmel.force.com/support/servlet/fileField?id=0BEG0000000HRvP, the SAM3X8E has 2 quadrature decoders in it. Now I am not being able to understand how can I initialize this second quadrature decoder. According to **Quadrature Decoder QDEC for SAM3/4 Devices_ApplicationNote_AT11483**  *Pg16* we have to first configure the IOPINS for QDEC1. I have to do that same task in Arduino IDE instead of Atmel Studio.

This is the code that I have found and works well to read encoder using QDEC0. However, I now need to read the encoder using the second quadrature decoder, whose input pins are TIOA6 , TIOB6 which correspond to Pin 5 and 4 of Arduino DUE. After reading the Atmel SAM3X datasheet, I think I should change "TC0" with "TC2" to make the second decoder work. However, this doesn't work. I think it does not work because channel 2 is busy in time base calculations.
In Application Note *5.52* **QDEC Speed Measurement Mode** point 2 says to Initialize TC0, TC1, TC2. If I wanted to used other encoder which timer instance will be used.

```
/*
** Quadrature Encoder on Arduino Due in "Speed Mode"
** Will not work on other Arduino types because of a specific hardware requirement.
**
** @bungle99 / 2014-02-28
**
** Many thanks to @Designservicecorp (notably post #32 and post #42) that gave me the base to work from.
**
** Uses *hardware* to do the heavy lifting of interpreting the Encoder output, which gives it significant
** advantage over other Arduino's for this use case. Eg many people have reported their Unos maxing out
** or skipping counts when interpretting high RPMs, whereas people using the Due in hardware mode have 
** reported better success with high RPMs.
**
** This particular example puts the hardware into "Speed" mode, whereas other examples in this thread use 
** "Position" mode (see posts 32, 42). The one example in the thread that attempts Speed calcs uses Position 
** Mode and uses an interrupt on the Z Index axis to manually apply a time period (needed to caculate speed) 
** on each rotation.
**
** This code below has been used in tests (using Lego NXT and a gear train for driving / comparison) to 
** ~3,500 RPM with a 1,024 PPR Encoder (4 x 1,024 Edges). The Arduino didn't seem to struggle and the 
** numbers (eg RPM) matched fairly closely with the Lego (eg as a sanity check, the calcs in the code look
** correct).
**
** I bought one of these encoders, which seems ok;
**
**   * http://proto-pic.co.uk/rotary-encoder-1024-p-r-quadrature/
**
** Great service from proto-pic. The encoder specs are officially
**
**   * http://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Robotics/E6B2Encoders.pdf
**
** But look an awful lot like this one too (which is easier to read)
**
**   * http://www.ia.omron.com/product/item/e6b27032r/index.html
**
** Note that this Encoder is rated at 5V min. I've successully powered it off the 5V Arduino pin header, 
** and it doesn't work off the 3.3V one. At 5V, the outputs need to be run through some resistors to bring
** them into tolerance of the Arduino inputs.
**
** The inputs are 2 and 13 (and optionally A6 for the index).
**
** The test hardware (some Lego NXT servos and gear train) was unable to turn any faster (more gears 
** stalled the servos) - eg the Arduino Due was not the limiting factor. At this speed, the Due Hardware 
** is dealing with approx 238,000 edges per second.
**
** This example offloads the speed calculation onto the hardware, meaning no interrupt is required. 
** In addition, the index is not required either, so it allows speeds to be seen even for rotations that 
** don't pass the index marker (for example, slow rotations needing a speed before a complete rotation). 
** That said, index is available if you want it and the docs suggest you can still use it (and others) as 
** interrupt if you wish. 
**
** NB There appears to be a myriad of features on the Chip that have not been touched. Eg you can still add
** interrupts to this code to do other things; eg passing the Z index, direction changes. There are also 
** filters available if your encoder suffers from noise (eg vibrations). All this is available to play with
** another day :)
**
** Code appears to work, but no guarantees. Understand it. Test it. Feedback to the group. YMMV. Don't blame 
** me if it doesn't work or expolodes!
*/

const int ENCODER_EDGES_PER_ROTATION = 3200;  // this depends on your encoder
const int ENCODER_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND = 10;        // this will need to be tuned depending on your use case...
const int LOOP_DELAY_MS = 1 * 1000;               // ... as will this (see comments in main code)

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);  
  delay(10);


  // Setup Quadrature Encoder
  // http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc11057.pdf
  // Section 37 p869 
  // Section 37.6.14 p885
  // Section 37.6.14.2 p890 Position and Rotation Measurement
  // Section 37.6.14.5 p891 Speed Measurement (what this is about)

  REG_PMC_PCER0 = PMC_PCER0_PID27
                | PMC_PCER0_PID28
                | PMC_PCER0_PID29;

  // Setup a channel in waveform mode (eg an input into the encoder to trigger the time based sampling)
  // Note some of the choices here impact calculations below and if you change them, you need to change
  // the next section to suit.
  // Section 37.7.11 p906 (also refer to Section 37.6.14.5 p891 for detail of what to set)
  REG_TC0_CMR2 = TC_CMR_TCCLKS_TIMER_CLOCK4 
               | TC_CMR_WAVE
               | TC_CMR_ACPC_TOGGLE 
               | TC_CMR_WAVSEL_UP_RC;

  // Now define the sample period, using the clock chosen above as the basis
  // Note that REG_TC0_CMR2 above is using CLOCK4; this is an 128 divisor. You need to change the
  // divisor below if you change the clock above. You could change the input clock and the RC mode to 
  // suit your app (eg how many pulses are you  expecting - depends on encoder type 
  // and slowest/normal/fastest rotation speed and what you want to do with the result).
  // Section 37.6.14.5 p891 notes you need to set this up, otherwise 0 comes out all the time :-)
  REG_TC0_RC2 = F_CPU / 128 / ENCODER_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND;

  // Setup a channel in capture mode
  // Section 37.7.10 p904 (also refer to Section 37.6.14.5 p891 for detail of what to set)
  REG_TC0_CMR0 = TC_CMR_ABETRG
               | TC_CMR_LDRA_EDGE
               | TC_CMR_LDRB_EDGE 
               | TC_CMR_ETRGEDG_EDGE 
               | TC_CMR_CPCTRG;

  // Enable features, noting Speed not Position is chosen
  // Section 37.7.2 p895 (also refer to Section 37.6.14.5 p891 for detail of what to set)

// 37.7.2 TC Block Mode Register
  REG_TC0_BMR = TC_BMR_QDEN
              | TC_BMR_SPEEDEN
              | TC_BMR_EDGPHA; //Pg 896

/*EDGPHA: EDGe on PHA count mode
0: edges are detected on both PHA and PHB.
1: edges are detected on PHA only.*/


  // Set everything going
  REG_TC0_CCR0 = TC_CCR_CLKEN | TC_CCR_SWTRG;  
  REG_TC0_CCR1 = TC_CCR_CLKEN | TC_CCR_SWTRG;  
  REG_TC0_CCR2 = TC_CCR_CLKEN | TC_CCR_SWTRG;  
}

void loop() {

  int iIndexCount = REG_TC0_CV1;  // Don't need this, but manual notes its available  
  int iSpeedPPP = REG_TC0_RA0;    // This is what we're really after (speed in Pulses Per sample Period)

  // which we can convert to rps or rpm easily
  double dSpeedRPS = ((iSpeedPPP / (ENCODER_EDGES_PER_ROTATION * 1.0)) * ENCODER_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND);
  double dSpeedRPM =  dSpeedRPS * 60;

  Serial.print("Speed ppp: ");
  Serial.print(iSpeedPPP);
  Serial.print(", ");
  Serial.print("Speed rps: ");
  Serial.print(dSpeedRPS);
  Serial.print(", ");
  Serial.print("Speed rpm: ");
  Serial.print(dSpeedRPM);
  Serial.print(", ");
  Serial.print("Indexes: ");
  Serial.print(iIndexCount);
  Serial.print(". ");
  Serial.println();

  // Slow down the main loop noting the Encoder can update independently in the background (we're
  // effectively polling it to find out the latest and greatest info on each loop around).
  delay(LOOP_DELAY_MS);
}
```

Additionally I wanted to ask what is the difference between REG_TC0_CMR2 REG_TC0_CMR0 and REG_TC0_CMR1 ? Two of them are used in the above code.

Motor with Encoder I am using is:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TC blocks are pretty much identical (except TC1 doesn't have wired some signals to pins)

So you have to copy registers containing `*_TC0_* =` and replace TC0 to TC2.

Plus PC25 and PC24 should be set to its alternate function PIO_PERIPH_B. Something like this:

```
  PIO_Configure(PIOC, PIO_PERIPH_B, PIO_PC25B_TIOA6, PIO_DEFAULT);
  PIO_Configure(PIOC, PIO_PERIPH_B, PIO_PC26B_TIOB6, PIO_DEFAULT);
```

Also TC6, TC7 and TC8 clocks must be enabled by:

```
REG_PMC_PCER1 = PMC_PCER1_PID33 | PMC_PCER1_PID34 | PMC_PCER1_PID35;
```

And TC_CMR0..2 are Channel Mode Registers for one of three timers/counters in one TC block. Again, these are the same, but WAVE mode dependent.

[image: TC_CMR WAVE=0]

[image: TC_CMR WAVE=1]

Full configuration:

```
  REG_PMC_PCER0 = PMC_PCER0_PID27 | PMC_PCER0_PID28 | PMC_PCER0_PID29;
  REG_PMC_PCER1 = PMC_PCER1_PID33 | PMC_PCER1_PID34 | PMC_PCER1_PID35;

  PIO_Configure(PIOB, PIO_PERIPH_B, PIO_PB25B_TIOA0, PIO_DEFAULT); // arduino pin 2
  PIO_Configure(PIOB, PIO_PERIPH_B, PIO_PB27B_TIOB0, PIO_DEFAULT); // arduino pin 13

  REG_TC0_CMR2  = TC_CMR_TCCLKS_TIMER_CLOCK4 | TC_CMR_WAVE | TC_CMR_ACPC_TOGGLE | TC_CMR_WAVSEL_UP_RC;
  REG_TC0_RC2   = F_CPU / 128 / 1;
  REG_TC0_CMR0  = TC_CMR_ABETRG | TC_CMR_LDRA_EDGE | TC_CMR_LDRB_EDGE | TC_CMR_ETRGEDG_EDGE | TC_CMR_CPCTRG;
  REG_TC0_BMR   = TC_BMR_QDEN | TC_BMR_SPEEDEN /*| TC_BMR_EDGPHA*/;
  REG_TC0_CCR0  = TC_CCR_CLKEN | TC_CCR_SWTRG;
  REG_TC0_CCR1  = TC_CCR_CLKEN | TC_CCR_SWTRG;
  REG_TC0_CCR2  = TC_CCR_CLKEN | TC_CCR_SWTRG;

  PIO_Configure(PIOC, PIO_PERIPH_B, PIO_PC25B_TIOA6, PIO_DEFAULT); // arduino pin 5
  PIO_Configure(PIOC, PIO_PERIPH_B, PIO_PC26B_TIOB6, PIO_DEFAULT); // arduino pin 4

  REG_TC2_CMR2  = TC_CMR_TCCLKS_TIMER_CLOCK4 | TC_CMR_WAVE | TC_CMR_ACPC_TOGGLE | TC_CMR_WAVSEL_UP_RC;
  REG_TC2_RC2   = F_CPU / 128 / 10;
  REG_TC2_CMR0  = TC_CMR_ABETRG | TC_CMR_LDRA_EDGE | TC_CMR_LDRB_EDGE | TC_CMR_ETRGEDG_EDGE | TC_CMR_CPCTRG;
  REG_TC2_BMR   = TC_BMR_QDEN | TC_BMR_POSEN /*| TC_BMR_EDGPHA*/;
  REG_TC2_CCR0  = TC_CCR_CLKEN | TC_CCR_SWTRG;
  REG_TC2_CCR1  = TC_CCR_CLKEN | TC_CCR_SWTRG;
  REG_TC2_CCR2  = TC_CCR_CLKEN | TC_CCR_SWTRG;
```

Comment: I have tried this , but it doesn't work. We are not getting any measurement....

Comment: @MasoodSalik also clocks must be enabled for channels 6-8. I though it's enabled for whole block by `REG_PMC_PCER0 = PMC_PCER_PID29` but it was just third counter in TC0.

Comment: I have enabled all the clocks using
`{ REG_PMC_PCER0 = PMC_PCER0_PID27
                    | PMC_PCER0_PID28
                    | PMC_PCER0_PID29
                     | PMC_PCER0_PID30
                      | PMC_PCER0_PID31;
 REG_PMC_PCER1 = PMC_PCER1_PID32
                    | PMC_PCER1_PID33
                    | PMC_PCER1_PID34
                     | PMC_PCER1_PID35; }`

Now I am able to read QDEN1 from pin 4 and 5 . QDEN0 from pin 2 and 13. I am now reading clicks_per_revoluion using REG_TC2_CV0 and  REG_TC0_CV0. Now i am trying to measure the speed